# Programmatically change the shell's cwd in a portable way

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd

I'd like to write a command line tool in C that acts as an advanced "cd" or "pushd/popd" command that can be ported to Windows/Mac/Linux. (Full details, in case you are curious, are at http://alsweigart.tumblr.com/post/4008393181/command-line-idea-up )

The problem is, when the user runs a program from the shell, changing the current working directory will change the program's cwd, instead of the shell's cwd.

Is there a way to write a program to do what I want, or will I have to resort to writing bash scripts/batch files?

Alternatively, is there a way I could pipe the output of a program to be run as a shell command? i.e. The program outputs "cd /foo/bar" and a shell script calls this program and runs its output as a shell command.

Answer (score 5):

In general, one process can't change the current directory of another process (this is true on both Windows and Unix systems). Therefore, a program that runs as a separate process outside a shell can't change the current directory of the shell.

You will likely have to use some combination of batch files and/or shell scripts to accomplish what you want to do. Note that although Windows batch files can change the current directory of the shell in which they run, this is *not* true of shell scripts on Unix. In the case of Unix, you will probably want to use shell *functions*, which do run in the same process. Note that writing shell functions is shell-specific, so you'd have to port your program to each Unix shell that you want to support, too.

On some Unix shells, you can make a shell script run in the context of the current shell using the `.` command. If your shell supports that, you can use a shell alias to run it so you don't have to type `.` in front of your command.

Comment: So on Unix `cd` must also always be a shell built-in?

Comment: That's correct. Implementing `cd` as an external process would make it impossible to change the current directory of the shell process.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating the working directory of a shell is something that must be done by the shell itself - you cannot write a program to do it. As for your second question, please post an example of what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to make a shell function which runs the program and then does a cd on the result.

```
mycd()
{
  cd `mycdprogram "$@"`
}
```

You can run it like `mycd Please change my directory to /tmp` or whatever arguments your program takes.

For the other command, you can do something like:

```
myrun()
{
   eval `myprogram "$@"`
}
```

And the shell will do whatever shell command myprogram generates.

All of this for POSIX shells of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(echo "cd /foo/bar")
```

That demonstrates how you might do such a thing with a POSIX shell. It's not portable with the Windows shell, of course.