# How to change the shell's current working directory in Go?

Tags: go

I want implement the `cd` command with Go, `main.go`:

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if flag.NArg() == 0 {
        curUser, err := user.Current()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        os.Chdir(curUser.HomeDir)
        // or like this
        // cmd := exec.Command("cd", curUser.HomeDir)
        fmt.Println(os.Getwd())   // ok in application
    }
}
```

But when I run `go run main.go` in shell, it still not switch to my home directory.

So how can I change my working directory in shell by running go files?

[image: code running]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115952/programmatically-change-the-shells-cwd-in-a-portable-way.

Comment: thanks a lot, they two are different process, shell current working directory could be changed by itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this; every child process has its own working directory inherited from the parent. In this case, your `cd` gets its working directory from its parent (your shell). A child process can't change the directory – or any other state – of the parent process.

This is basic process separation. Allowing child processes to influence their parent would have all sorts of security and usability issues.

Shells implement `cd` as a "special builtin". It's not an external binary:

```
$ where cd
cd: shell built-in command
```

In other words, when the shell runs the `cd` command it's run in the same process as the rest of the shell.

The basic logic of a shell's REPL looks something like:

```
for {
    line := waitForInputLine()
    switch {
        case strings.HasPrefix(line, "cd"):
            os.chdir(strings.Split(line, " ")[1])

        // ..check other builtins and special cases./

        default:
            runBinary(line)
    }
}
```

There is no way you can implement that in an external binary, no matter which language you use to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete solution, but it is worth mentioning that you can load golang builtins. I will update this answer with a more complete implementation if I find/make one.

Bash (and many other shells) support loadable builtins. [This library](https://github.com/JohnStarich/goenable), [and others](https://github.com/bashgo/goenable) support builtins, but it's not clear how to modify shell variables (like `PWD`).

The name is a play on the `enable` builtin which is used for loading these extensions. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/enable