# Change parent shell directory from Go

Tags: go

How can I write a Go program that will behave as 'cd ' does?

I tried running a Command, but it didn't work.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("cd", "/media/")
    err := cmd.Run()
    log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't "cd" work in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the shell's current working directory in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435908/how-to-change-the-shells-current-working-directory-in-go)

Comment: @ThunderCat No, both have different implication. One is to "touch txt" in a particular working directory, the other is to change the caller's directory..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I write a Go program that will behave as 'cd ' does?

**This is *impossible*** on POSIX systems (even by using any other programming languages).

Because each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), including the parent shell process, has its *own* current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Hence `cd` has to be a [shell builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) (invoking the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call done by the shell process itself), it cannot be done by some [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), because the shell forks a new process to run every command (using some executable, i.e. which is not a builtin).

Read some good Unix or Linux programming book, such as the [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), for an explanation. And a good book on [Operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), such as [*Operating systems: three easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) would explain you why is it so (and cannot reasonably be otherwise, in POSIX-like or Unix-like systems).

Your code is [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) (with `cmd.Run`) a new process, and *that* child process *only* is changing its working directory. See also [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) & [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).

To invoke the  [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call in your Go code, use [`os.Chdir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chdir). That would only affect your process (and all future child processes created by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), which inherit the working directory of their parent process) and of course won't change the working directory of your parent process (which often is your shell).

To get the current working directory (with the [getcwd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) system call) of your current process, use [`os.Getwd`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd) in your Go code (and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53913521/841108)).

On Linux, you could use `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details) to query the working directory of other processes. For example, run `ls -l /proc/$$/cwd` in your shell. In Go code you'll use [os.Readlink](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Readlink) on a path like `/proc/1234/cwd` etc. Of course you cannot change the working directory of some other process (the only working directory that you are allowed to change is the one of your own process, using [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html))

As commented by [David Budsworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121631/david-budworth), you could adopt a weird *convention* that: 1. Your `prog` program writes a valid (and suitably quoted for the shell) directory path on the standard output, and nothing else. 2. You *always* use that `prog` program with a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), something like `cd $(prog args...)` (which could become the body of a [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) or an [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html), etc...), then your shell (not your `prog`) would change directory as output by your program.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually trying to implement bookmarking program that cd into 'bookmark' name which translates to a directory, any idea on how to workaround this ?

Comment: It is impossible, unless you invoke *directly* `os.Chdir` from your program (and that *won't* change the working directory of the parent shell, only of the process running your program and all its future child processes).  Again, you need to read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/). There cannot be any "workaround".

Comment: Well, the workaround is create an alias that runs the go program which list the path.. `alias gcd=goprogram cd a`

Comment: That is not a workaround. You can't change the fact that every process has its own working directory, and that it is impossible to change the working directory of some other process (such as your parent shell)

Comment: can do via an alias that does `alias gcd=cd [backtick] goprog foo [backtick]` (not sure how to type a literal backtick in comments as that makes a code snippet.  but this will run `goprog` with `foo` as an argument, and then `cd` to whatever that outputs

Comment: You'll better use `$(goprog foo)` instead of backticks

Comment: If it is impossible, how https://github.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide does it ?