# Linux style pushd in windows

Tags: linux, windows, directory, pushd

I am happy using `pushd` and `dirs -v` in Linux. `pushd` can store directories into a stack while `dirs -v` can show items in directory stacks with index. I can then use `pushd +n` to switch to any index in the stack without remove it from stack. This saves me a lot of time switching between various directories.

Windows also has `pushd`. But it is lacking of `dirs` command. To show items in stack, `pushd` without any argument can be used, however, there is no index, I can neither find a way to jump to an arbitrary entry. The only thing I can do in Windows is use `popd` to change directory to the top of the stack one by one.

Is there any facility I can use in windows providing the functionality of Linux version `pushd` and `dirs -v`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one answer this question, I wrote a script set myself to achieve this in windows [windows-cds](https://github.com/ericsunplus/windows-cds).

Also I find that there is a similar cross-platform utility [autojump](https://github.com/wting/autojump) which provide more comprehensive functionalities, but the setup is a bit complex.

So I am happy to stick to my own wheels :)

Comment: You can also see [Programmatically change the shell's cwd in a portable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115952/programmatically-change-the-shells-cwd-in-a-portable-way?r=SearchResults&s=3|30.9712) for a similar cross-platform solution written in C. (also, good effort on writing your own and hosting it on a development platform)

Comment: Every road leads to ROMA :)